# Installing Trac on Windows

Tags: windows-7, python, trac

I am new to project management and I have no idea about Python.  Now, I want to setup the Trac program.

I read the installation process on their web site, but I could not understand it.  Can you help me with installation please?

At the moment I have installed these to my laptop:

1. python-2.5.msi
2. setuptools-0.6c7.win32-py2.5.exe
3. Genshi-0.5.win32-py2.5.exe
4. uberSVN-1110_beta.exe

What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Based on file extensions, you're on Windows. Please provide more information about your environment, including which version of Windows you're using (including whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit). How far through the instructions did you get?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, this is my first time I am here.

Comment: I use Windows7 32-bit

Comment: I searched in google, but did not really understand. Because this is my first time to install Trac. It is complex.

Comment: Now I have stopped. And do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a great first-time experience with Trac, try the [all-in-one solution from BitNami](http://bitnami.org/stack/trac).

They have software stacks for a variety of OS's, including Windows, and there's everything included that you probably might need to just start using a particular software application. I.e. for Trac there is Apache, Python, SQLite and Subversion included in the installer. Can't think of an easier way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [URL](http://how-to-solutions.com/how-to-install-trac-on-windows.html) via Trac's site that was dead, which was a set of point-and-click instructions on Windows. Using http://web.archive.org, I found a version of the page that could help you.

http://web.archive.org/web/20101123093021/http://how-to-solutions.com/how-to-install-trac-on-windows.html

I'm not going to paste the instructions here, because it's quite long-winded. Also, this is kind-of outside of the scope of SuperUser so I wouldn't be surprised if the question is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but link is not opening...

Comment: Did you use the second one or the first one. The second one worked for me but the first is dead.

Comment: I used second one, it returns 404 not found...

Comment: I've just tested it again and it works for me. Copy and paste the entire line into your browser's address bar, starting with the `http://web` and ending with `windows.html`.

Comment: Could you please type it here exactly which one?

Comment: I can confirm Randolph's link opens for me in Chrome and Firefox without any problems. Also, here's another link for this topic that might be useful: http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2010/02/08/137853.aspx